# ruby print hash values in iteration

Tags: ruby

This is happening and it seems weird to me.

The following code prints nothing but blank lines:

```
matz = { "First name" => "Yukihiro",
         "Last name" => "Matsumoto",
         "Age" => 47,
         "Nationality" => "Japanese",
         "Nickname" => "Matz"
}

matz.each do |k|
  puts  matz[k]
end
```

if I change that to

```
matz.each do |k|
  puts k
  puts  matz[k]
end
```

works

also

```
matz.each do |k,v|
  puts  matz[k]
end
```

works

Anybody has got any explain please

Comment: _Sidenote_: `hash.each { |k, v| sume_usage_of_hash_here }` is **not** idiomatic. One should not use the object being iterated inside a loop. There are many helpers like mappers, reducers etc that help to avoid that. In this particular case it even makes no sense, since `matz[k]` is what is returned as the second block argument. Violating idiomatic patterns always leads to misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In:

```
matz.each do |k|
  puts  matz[k]
end
```

each `k` will be an array that represents a key-value pair such as `["First name", "Yukihiro"]`. Since none of these pairs is a key of the hash `matz`, `puts  matz[k]` is the same as `puts nil`.

Comment: So why the second one works? If I puts k first then puts matz[k] works?

Comment: `puts matz[k]` does not, all the output you see is produced by `puts k`, just try to remove the `puts matz[k]` line. Try `puts ["First name", "Yukihiro"]` and you’ll see the same output.

Comment: In the second one, `puts matz[k]` is not working. `puts k` is working.